# how can we assign a javascript array from mysql database with the help of php?

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to know if we can select data from the database using php and assign it to a javascript array? 
if so what would be the syntax?

I wrote the code below but it is not working

```
$js_array = "[";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_name FROM tbl_item");
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) ) {
    $js_array .= $row[0]; 
    $js_array .= ",";
}
$js_array{ strlen($js_array)-1 } = ']';

 ?>

<script>
var cities = <?php echo  $js_array; ?>
for(var i=0; i<4;i++)
alert(cities.length);

</script>
```

Comment: You should manually build JSON. Have a look at the output. You will create something like `[name1, name2, name3]` which will result in an error because `nameX` are undefined variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I populate a javascript array with values from a database using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416908/how-can-i-populate-a-javascript-array-with-values-from-a-database-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is converting to [JSON](http://json.org) with [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
// with $js_array being a true array
var cities = <?php echo json_encode($js_array)?>;
```

Note, that there are [esoteric cases](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset), where this solution might not work. On the other hand, the advantage is, that json_encode takes over all quoting needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 0):

You should not echo the array object.

Iterate the array and echo the value.

```
<?php foreach( $js_array as $value) echo "'$value',"; ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE because of the trailing comma. You will have to work around this complicately or use implode().