# Can a canvas be created using mySQL data?

Tags: html, mysql, canvas, graph

I want to draw some simple graphs.

I was wondering if mySQL data can be used alongside the canvas function for such a feature?

Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: ofcourse you can, do some googling. nobody's gonna write your code for you

Comment: Did some research but didn't get the answer I was looking for. Definitely didn't expect anyone to write the code for me.

Comment: No problem, you could actually take a few hints from ThiefMaster's answer. First search for some examples, search "draw graph html canvas". Learn how to draw a graph in html canvas, create a sample page. In the examples they would be using static data. Now you want to load graph data from your mysql db. Search for "ajax json php mysql example", believe me there are plenty of these on the internet. Now write the code to fetch graph data using ajax in your sample html page. Thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of the previous responses completely misunderstood what you are asking. You're basically looking for a way to leverage data stored in a MySQL database and use it to populate the X and Y values of a basic HTML 5 graph (basic optional output for the canvas API).  Sounds like you already know how to make such a chart with HTML 5 and the examples with "static" are great.  Now, you want to learn how to populate with dynamic data from a database like MySQL.  I've been looking for the same answer and found this thread here at stackoverflow that should help you [How can I populate a javascript array with values from a database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416908/how-can-i-populate-a-javascript-array-with-values-from-a-database-using-php)

If you know how to connect to a database and send basic SQL queries to your database with PHP, the rest is fairly easy.  That URL outlines a number of different ways to do it, but the one that I think is the cleanest is to JSON encode your data retrieved via PHP.  Here's the sample I'm going to try.

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row['key'];
}
echo 'var array = '.json_encode($array).';';
```

Notice that all of the code is PHP so you'll need to use the correct open and closing tags.  The last line is where the retrieved data, stored into a PHP array, is encoded with JSON thus creating an array that javascript can use.  Now, write your canvas code and loop through the encoded array to dynamically create a graph.

I hope that points you further in the right direction...and shame on those previous responders that were so arrogant.

Comment: Thanks for responding despite the age of the thread. Fortunately I am comfortable using PHP and have in fact created the graphs I was referring to using SVG. Unlike TheifMaster, I do not(and still don't) have extensive experience with web development. Kudos to you for not being a d bag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, obviously that's possible. You'd JSON-encode the data to make it available to your JavaScript code and then use it like any other data. Because that's what it is after all: *Data*. Doesn't matter where it's stored / comes from.