# Array from PHP to Javascript is null

Tags: javascript, php

I've been working on a personal project for a few days now, everything was working nicely, but since I've started on it again 2 hours ago I'm getting the following problem:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
   $Testarray = array_map('str_getcsv', $content=file('Shows.csv'), array_fill(0,count($content), ";"));
   foreach($Testarray as $array)
    {
     foreach($array as $item)
     {
      print($item);
      print '<br/>';
     }
    }
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var array = <?php echo json_encode($Testarray); ?>;
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm allmost afraid to ask, but the 'var array' in Javascript is null.
$Testarray is filled correctly, it prints the correct values. I've tried to do the same with a simple String and that works without a problem.

I've also tried
    var array = new Array();
prior to filling it. No effect.

Edit after trincot's reply:

```
var array = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($Testarray); ?>');
```

Gives the following result in "Sources" in Chrome:

```
var array = JSON.parse(' ');
```

So it still doesn't seem to return anything.

Edit2: var_dump($testarray) (Sources in Chrome):

[image: var_dump testarray]

Final edit: The cause of the problem was a value in the xlsx file I exported from to a CSV file.
The xlsx had a value with the `ô` character, which was replaced with `�` in the CSV file. This caused for a nested null array in PHP and made everything go boom.

Using [Eric's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131662/4080192) answer from another question, saving the xlsx file as xls and then saving the xls as CSV did the trick.

Comment: You should put quotes around `<?php ... ?>` to make it a string for Javascript, and then parse it as JSON

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: 
- [How can I populate a javascript array with values from a database using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416908/how-can-i-populate-a-javascript-array-with-values-from-a-database-using-php)

Comment: json_encode() dumps out json only. It would **NOT** spit out a "json.parse()" call. that'd be entirely redundant. `var foo = JSON.parse(4);` and `var foo = 4` are essentially identical.

Comment: I wonder, why nobody said, that you have a spaghetti code. It is not a good style to mix client and server code this way. Try to separate logic - divide and conquer. At least you should use some php template engine.

Comment: It might not be up to standard, but I can't automatically parse a CSV and then draw these locations via Google Maps API with just php or javascript.

Comment: I would not call this issue resolved at this moment. "Invalid Character" is not a correct resolution. `json_encode` is designed to correctly deal with most unicode characters, certainly `ô`. The problem is probably related to the use of non-UTF-8 encoded strings, and so this issue should not be considered closed yet. NB: issues are not solved by adding "[Solved..] to the title, but by accepting an answer.

Comment: Noted. Most likely it went wrong in the export from Excel to csv somewhere. It's not a problem that needs solving though, for now swapping the ô with an o (manually) fixed it.

Comment: I will go through your suggestions during the weekend. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine. JSON can be injected like that into Javascript, and it is abnormal that it just outputs a blank.

The `var_dump` output you added to the question confirms that there truly is an array in PHP which shows no apparent reason for this effect. I suggested to debug this, by outputting the JSON element by element:

```
    var array = [
    <?php
    foreach($Testarray as $array) {
        $output = json_encode($array); 
        echo "  $output,\n";
    }
    ?>
    ];
```

You reported that the first values were output correctly, but a problem occurred for a value with character `ô`. However, this is not the source of the problem. In a good configuration, the following code:

```
echo json_encode("ô");
```

will return: *\u00f4*

Which is the [correct unicode number](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f4/index.htm), and [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/), and will not lead to the effect you are having. Note that the last link also states:

> The character encoding of JSON text is always Unicode. UTF-8 is the only encoding that makes sense on the wire, but UTF-16 and UTF-32 are also permitted.

The problem you are facing really is related to **character encoding**.

To solve this you should make sure the data is in UTF-8 encoding before passing it to `json_encode`. If you get it from a CSV file then make sure that file is saved as UTF-8.

The above would probably solve your issue, but it would be good also to follow the W3C instructions in [*Declaring character encodings in HTML*](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en), including (also) these:

- Declare the UTF-8 encoding in your HTML, for example by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `head` section. Also start your file with `<!DOCTYPE html>`;
- Make sure your PHP file is saved in UTF-8 character encoding. Most editors have an option for this, either under the *Save As* menu, or in some *Preferences* menu. If the editor offers the choice, include the [*Byte Order Mark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). For example, *notepad++* offers this possibility in the *Encoding* menu;
- If you still face problems, verify PHP configuration settings concerning character encoding and HTTP output encoding. If you have non-default, non-UTF-8 values specified there, this may be the cause of your problems.

PHP.ini [settings that influence encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php):

```
mbstring.internal_encoding    = UTF-8
mbstring.http_output          = UTF-8
```

Comment: This gives the following result in the Sources in Chrome:

var array = JSON.parse(' ');

Comment: That means that you have a problem in PHP and the variable `$Testarray` really is empty (null or blank string, but not an array). Do you have errors reading the CSV file? `echo $content;` to check if there is anything read.

Comment: That's where the foreach echo's in the php script in the top is for. The array is correctly filled and printed on the page.

Comment: Just for testing (I know this is not what you need): could you only `json_encode` the first array element, and see if that works? `json_encode($Testarray[0])` ... adding the `[0]`.

Comment: That does return the right nested array!

Is it just not possible to send multidimensional arrays from PHP to Javascript?

Comment: No, that should not be a problem. My hunch is that there might be a size problem. I put an alternative in my answer based on this finding. It would be interesting to see if something goes wrong halfway.

Comment: At last, redemption.

The 97th entry had the letter ô in it, JSON couldn't handle it and it caused for a nested null array.

You have my semi-eternal gratitude

Comment: One possible reason why json_encode failed on that, is that your PHP file is not saved in UTF-8 encoding. It would be worth checking if changing the file encoding (with save-as or options in your editor) resolves the problem.

Comment: Testing with `echo json_encode("ô");` I just get `"\u00f4"`. Therefore I think you have found a symptom of a deeper problem, but the fault seems not with `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($Testarray); ?>")`