# display price on textbox based on item selection in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am having trouble displaying the price of an item in a `select` in an `input`. Here is my code so far:

```
<table border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="productName" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Product</option>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblProduct ORDER BY productName ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $test123 = "var dtPRD= new Array();\n"; 
    while ( $data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='{".$data['productCode']."}'>".$data['productName']."
</option>";
$test123 .= "dtPRD['" . $data['productName'] . "'] = {productPrice:'" . 
($data['productPrice']). "'};\n"; 
}
?>
</select>       
</td>
<td>
Price<input type="text" name="productPrice">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">   
<?php 
echo $test123; 
?> 
function changeValue(productName){ 
document.getElementByName'namaProduk').value = 
dtPRD[productName].productPrice;
}; 
</script>
```

For example, if item A is chosen from the dropdown, I want the price of item A to show up in my `input`. Right now, my code isn't doing this.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - I used an `array` to achieve what you want!

You can also generate a multidimensional array to point to the products.

To get the array from your php or your database: explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416908/how-can-i-populate-a-javascript-array-with-values-from-a-database-using-php)!

```js
var array = ["919$","929$","939$","949$"];

function changeValue(productName) {
  document.getElementById('productPrice').value = array[productName];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="productName" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
        <option >Product</option>
        <option name="product" value="0">Product-Name 1</option>
        <option name="product" value="1">Product-Name 2</option>
        <option name="product" value="2">Product-Name 3</option>
        <option name="product" value="3">Product-Name 4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      Price<input type="text" id="productPrice">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: still wont work to display the database record to the text field. but thx for your suggestion :)

Comment: yeah for sure you have to get the array from your php or your database! but thats explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416908/how-can-i-populate-a-javascript-array-with-values-from-a-database-using-php)! :)